# Moved Wordpress from localhost on my desktop to a localhost on my laptop but it's not loading

Tags: wordpress, web, localhost, hosts

So I copied the /var/www/html directory and exported the database of my Wordpress site into the /var/www directory on my laptop (running Linux Ubuntu in VirtualBox).

However, when I open up my browser and enter 127.0.0.1 - it loads a different website that is also in the /var/www directory.

I am new to all of this so I can only speculate that I have to configure the hosts file somehow to recognize the html directory containing my WordPress site?

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will highly recommend using a plugin like [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to make a copy of a site. It is much easier than the manual way, where you move the files by you self and edit the database to match the new environment.

Do you copy your site to /var/www/html or /var/www/html/(a folder)?
In the case that your site is in a folder, you need to access it through 127.0.0.1/folderName

Comment: Thank you, Ahmad. I will try this later and let you know if it worked. Appreciate your quick response.